# Are char16_t and char32_t part of the std namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, types

I recently learned that using `size_t` as opposed to `std::size_t` in C++ is non-standard, and had to change my code because of it. I've read in some other answers that `char16_t` and `char32_t` are also introduced as typedefs, however intellisense only recognizes them without `std::`, and I don't know which header they come from, except the C header `<uchar.h>`, according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char16_t).

Should I prefix `std::` for these types? And if so, which C++ header are they defined in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read in some other answers that char16_t and char32_t are also introduced as typedefs

Either these answers are wrong or you are misunderstanding what you read (or they were talking about C).

`char16_t` and `char32_t` are [*keywords* in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) (unlike `size_t`). They are fundamental types, just like `int` and `float`. They are types distinct from all other types, but they do have an underlying type (`std::uint_least16_t` and `std::uint_least32_t` respectively).

In C11, `char16_t` and `char32_t` are typedefs defined in the header `<uchar.h>`. Maybe the answer was talking about C.

Comment: Interesting, I feel like it's a bit strange to have both typedef'd types and fundamental types use _t, and some of both to not. Def a bit confusing. This answers the question, thank you.

Comment: Also, yes, they were probably talking about C. I assumed it'd be a similar situation as size_t, but apparently that's not the case : )

Comment: And because `char16_t` and `char32_t` are keywords, `std::char16_t` and `std::char32_t` are syntax errors.

Comment: Before the 2011 standards, `char16_t` and `char32_t` were part of neither C nor C++.   From C11 they are typedefs for an optionally supported type (introduced in C99) named `uint16_least_t`.   Before C++11, `char16_t` and `char32_t` were not keywords, but some C++ compilers before 2011 were also C compilers and (although not required by C99) had `char16_t` and `char32_t` as typedefs.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 and later, `char16_t` and `char32_t` are built-in types of the C++ language itself, like `char` and `wchar_t` are. They are not part of the standard library, so no, they are not in the `std::` namespace, or defined in any header file.